# Dynamically get top level package in source root

Tags: java, reflection, path

I world like to get a root package where inner package branching starts.

For example: `src/main/java/com/my/pack/example`

and inside there is a fist occurance of multiple packages: `inner1` and `inner2`

Given this structure I want to get `com.my.pack.example`

I know I can iterate over packages starting from some class deep inside and do some filtering. but is there any easier way or existing util?

Comment: Why not `com.my.pack.example`?

Comment: What should happen if you have both `com.example` and `net.example` in the source folder?

Comment: then return them both